# Why can I see files on the SD card on Android, but not on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, android, sd-card, micro-sd-card, total-commander

I have a backup process from my phone that seems to be working well, but I'm confused about why this is happening:

1. I move files on my phone (android 7.0.1) to my external storage (micro sd card 64GB) *[free space was 1.4GB]*
2. turn off phone, remove sd card, put into USB sd card reader, plug USB into computer
3. Open explorer windows (2: one for the sd card, one for the destination dir)
4. Move/Delete files
5. Confirm in Windows Explorer that free space is created *[~7GB used of 64GB]*, files are gone from SD and spot-check that they are readable in backup location
6. eject drive safely, remove USB reader, remove card from reader, insert card into phone, turn phone on
7. Check external sd card using Total Commander on my Android, see the "moved" files still there, readable, reporting at full size, while free space is also still there *[Total Commander Android reporting ~7GB used]*.

I'm not doing any kind of secure delete, so I'm not overwriting the files with zeroes or anything like that...

**I assume that Windows is deleting the headers and leaving the files intact, but Total Commander should not see these files, right?**

**What is happening here? Why can I still see the files on the SD Card using TotalCommander on Android, but not on Windows?**

*NOTE: the sd card is definitely NOT write protected.*

Comment: Sounds like windows isn't working. Put the card back in windows and read it again, what's there this time? Might want to double-check the copying with a hash (md5/crc32 even)

Comment: Try to use xcopy or move command to move files on your SD card.
Then use DIR command to Displays the contents.
Also disable the security software and Windows Defender in case security software can’t detect files and delete them.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are actually putting the files on the SD card, right?  Android typically has partitions within the phone's internal storage, so the OS partition can be protected from where downloaded files, imagery from the camera etc are stored.  This partition is commonly mounted as "external storage" i.e. not the system partition, and is easy to mistake for an installed SD card when transferring files around.  It could be that you have copied the files, and you are seeing the originals on the phone still.

Comment: Yes, I am definitely putting the files on the SD card. I am successfully getting them from my phone onto my computer. The issue is around the fact that when I use Total Commander on my Android, after the process is complete, the files are _still_ on the SD card

Comment: @Xen2050 Windows still doesn't see the files on the SD Card when I put the card back into the PC.

Fortunately everything is backed up, there is no danger of losing files. The process was successful in accomplishing all goals: free space and securely store the files. It's just _really weird_ that the files are still readable from the SD card even though they have been "deleted".

Comment: " It could be that you have copied the files, and you are seeing the originals on the phone still." -- @Baldrickk  This seems the most plausible answer I've seen so far... worth investigating, though I'm fairly certain I'm looking at the external SD card and not a second non-system partition of the internal one, still worth double checking.

Comment: it's the sort of thing that I would myself say the same "of course I did it right" but it's also a mistake that I have definitely made myself more than once - getting the storage mixed up.  sometimes it's even called SD card - just to make it really easy to mix them up.

Comment: So it turns out that Windows simply isn't deleting the files, but believes that it is. After a restart of my PC the OS can read the files on the card again... heh. But yeah, totally easy mistake to have made. kind of wish I had ;) But no, Windows thinks it's smarter than it is. haha :P

Comment: Make that an answer, please. Although we have not really gone to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe windows just moved the files to a "Recycle Bin" folder, and they're still on the card. Total Commander in Android is showing all the files on the card.

Comment: It's odd. It shouldn't have recycled them, as I held shift when I deleted them, getting the confirmation that I would be permanently deleting them. Something about the SD card maybe being corrupt... Windows can't delete the files from them, but thinks it is. I should probably replace it before I lose data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like there is mold filesystem corruption and Windows is mounting the filesystem read only.  Try doing a filesystem check (checkdusj) and see if it fixes any corruption.

Comment: chkdsk and fsck both report no errors.

Comment: What’s, Mold filesystem?